# VBA and MSWord: Use multiple values of a find parameter in Find/Execute routine

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I have a Find/Execute routine that looks for paragraphs in my custom style, `Bullet_Type_1_Level_1`, which is a custom bulleted list style, and processes the paragraphs. (It checks each paragraph in the given range to see if it terminates in a period or not, but that's not important for this question). The routine currently works fine, but I want to expand it to search for additional levels--which translates into additional styles--of my outline list and to search for a style in another list, too. Is there a *compact* way to have my code also look for paragraphs in `Bullet_Type_1_Level_2` and `numlist_Level_1` (and process them, too) while it's at it? Here's the guts of my existing code:

```
For Each para In RangeToCheck.Paragraphs
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Style = "Bullet_Type_1_Level_1"
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
    Do While .Found = True 'Look for the specified style
        strSentence = Selection.Text
        'Test the string using a block of code that I'm omitting, for brevity.
        'Finally, depending on what happened, put or don't a period at the end of the original range.        
End With
Next para
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to do the same thing (the omitted code) to each of the three styles?

Comment: To any paragraph that is in any one of the three styles, yes.

Comment: I think I figured out how to do it. First, remove the Selection.Find and related code. Then, since I'm processing each paragraph anyway, just have an If/Then loop that checks to see if one of three things is true. If at least one of them is true, then I process the paragraph: If para.Style = "A" Or para.Style = "B" Or para.Style = "C" Then...Else 'do nothing End If.

Comment: @JoshG If you have solved your own question, feel free to answer it (that is allowed here) and mark it as the accepted answer to let others know you no longer are in need of assistance. Thanks!

Comment: So, you don't really need to specify the `.Wrap` criterion?

Comment: @BobRodes, true. If I change the code from being a Find/Execute block to instead just being an If/Then/EndIf block, there's no need for several lines that are currently there.

Comment: Right, I was making sure that you didn't actually need the functionality for some reason. When you specify `Wrap` as you have it here, you're saying that if you start your search at a place other than the beginning of the file and encounter the end of the file, you stop rather than continuing from the beginning of the file up to the initial search point. I don't see why it had to be specified at all, but I was making sure that you didn't have that need for a reason I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another loop.

Declare `i` (or more meaningful variable name), and loop through that.

```
Dim i As Long
For Each para In RangeToCheck.Paragraphs
    For i = 1 To 3
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = ""
            Select Case i
            Case 1
                .Style = "Bullet_Type_1_Level_1"
            Case 2
                .Style = "Bullet_Type_1_Level_2"
            Case 3
                .Style = "numlist_Level_1"
            End Select
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Execute
            Do While .Found = True 'Look for the specified style
                strSentence = Selection.Text
                'Test the string using a block of code that I'm omitting, for brevity.
                'Finally, depending on what happened, put or don't a period at the end of the original range.
        End With
    Next i
Next para
```

Probably not the prettiest solution out there - word is not my strong point ☺.

Comment: Very nice. I like it! I, too, came up with a solution, but yours is just as good, I think.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach that may be quicker if there are paragraphs that are none of those Styles:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 3
  With RangeToCheck
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ""
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Style = "Bullet_Type_1_Level_" & i
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found = True
      If .InRange(RangeToCheck) = False Then Exit Do
      Select Case i
        Case 1 'Do something for Bullet_Type_1_Level_1
        Case 2 'Do something for Bullet_Type_1_Level_2
        Case 3 'Do something for Bullet_Type_1_Level_3
      End Select
      If ActiveDocument.Range.End = RangeToCheck.Range.End Then Exit Do
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
Next
```